# Eclipse 3.6 freeze on autocomplete/quick fix

Tags: java, eclipse, freeze

I have a problem that seems to come up both with autocomplete and quick fix. Sometimes when I use cmd+1 for quick fix dialog, Eclipse freezes and however long I wait (30 min at least), nothing happens. When inspected in activity monitor, it seems to exhibit little to no processor activity.

I have a Mac with OSX 10.6, and Helios with no weird plugins. I program in java, so I use very standard features.

Is this a known bug? I have tried to google *a*  *lot* to find useful info. I am not very good at reading bug reports though, and the concept of feature freeze kind of taints my search results.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it work with a new workspace?

Comment: Does it happen when you use code templates too?

Answer (score 2):

As for Eclipse you can not know what is happening. The whole platform is a set of plugins, and the requirements (for example responsiveness) are not strict for them. So a third party or even a bundled plugin can cause such a failure. So most of times you cannot have a clue about what is wrong. Some stuff you can do:

1. while hanging unplug your network connection. If you are behind a proxy for example, a plugin can wait for a long time on network io
2. you can check with for example resource monitor, which file eclipse opened. Some of the opened file handlers can have relation with the problem
3. edit .classpath file in project where code completion freezes, and it will "reset" your project stuff in eclipse
4. you can browse .metadata folder in eclipse workspace and you can guess which folder to remove temporaly. After removing, try if error is still present
5. create a new workspace and import projects into it
6. if new workspace do not work, then the eror is in configuration folder in eclipse root, and you can play the same thing like in step 4
7. use a brand new eclipse

+1. Maybe some new plugin is responsible. In eclipse Help/about/installation details/Installation history tab you can revert to some older set of plugins.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you encounter known and already fixed [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317979).

Comment: went back to galileo right now :) also had the feeling that the old version didnt had this "error" / but

Comment: The bug you referred t in your answer is not definitively fixed. Whatever fixes they mention there did not work for me :|

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed after deleting all the files in the below directory

```
configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\.manager


.fileTableLock
.fileTable.1
.fileTable.2
```

There will be fileTable lock files, delete all those files